# JQuery JSONP turn result into PHP array

Tags: php, jquery, jsonp

I have been racking my small brain for ages now, so can this be done? if so how.  I return a json array via jQuery Ajax request like this

`dataType: 'jsonp', data: "somedata=this", jsonp: 'jsonp_callback', url: url,`

I get the data OK like this (Where field is one key in the array) - I know it's there because it appends properly.

`for (var key in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    jQuery('body').append(data[key]['Field']+'<br />');
  }`

But can I convert the returned data to a PHP array? which is really what I want to do

Comment: You mean http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php?

Comment: Sorry Matt don't mean json_decode I really want to get the Javascript variable into a PHP one, guess it will have to be AJAX'd somehow

Comment: There's only a few ways to transfer server side objects to client. Basically you have XML, JSON and you can serialize something. Best method today is JSON if you ask me. In PHP you can encode your php array to convert it to json, then javascript can look at it and interpret it as well. But it's like your saying i want to take a PHP array and then pass it off to java or C, this just doesn't work.

Comment: Agreed, but I may be missing something, I use JQuery getjson, but can it be done "directly in PHP" i.e. using something like Curl to return the array NOT the content so I can manipulate the array serverside?

Comment: so you are getting the json data from another website and then passing it on to your server? You want to just make a call from your server to get the json from another server? Is that correct? If so, then yes you can use cURL and grab that content. You could probably even do file_get_contents.

Comment: The data is going to be useless until a php script is loaded, so just push the data via ajax & store it to the database and use it when you next load a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK decided to go a different route all together and use Curl